# star not show in rails 3.0.9 - ajaxful_rating gem

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I using rails 3.0.9.

My Gemfile:

```
gem 'ajaxful_rating', :git => 'git://github.com/edgarjs/ajaxful-rating.git', :branch => "rails3"
```

I setup as ajaxful-rating document but star not show.

View image:http://awesomescreenshot.com/0c38t3g94.

please help me solved this problem!!

Comment: Try using the 3.0.0.beta8 gem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must update ajaxful_rating.css to display image

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem in my rails Rails 3.2.8 app. I think the generator still uses the old assets pipeline way.

Go to the assets folder created by the generator in the root of your project. You will find to folders `images` and `stylesheets`. Inside the images folders there is another folder called `ajaxful_rating`. Copy both images to `app/assets/images`. Then find `ajaxful_rating.css.scss` in the stylesheet folder and copy it to `app/assets/stylesheets` directory.

Modify the `background` css property around lines 10 and 81 to read like `background: image-url("star.png") left -1000px repeat-x;` and `background-image: image-url("star_small.png");` respectively.

You may now safely delete the assets folder in the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

I confronted this problem and **SOLVED**. I used gem 'ajaxful_rating', '3.0.0.beta8'

- Reason of error: ajaxful_rating created new assets folder (same level with app, db, lib, config, etc) inside your app_name folder. Therefore, ajaxful_rating.css.scss and stars images were not copied into your app/assets folder.

**+ How to solve: just copy ajaxful_rating.css.scss and images in assets folder created by ajaxful_rating to your *app/assets*.**